# Replacing missing values in R by given information in other columns

Tags: r

Let’s say I have a big dataframe in R listing item numbers and brand numbers.

Each brand can have multiple item numbers, the item numbers, however, can only have one corresponding brand number.

Is there a fast way of computing and replacing missing brand entries (NA values),  as indicated below, leaving NA values, where no accurate replacement can be found.

```
trainset <- data.frame("brand" = c(1,2,3,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,2,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), "item" = c(50, 100, 300,200,100,100,100,50,200,300,100,50,200,900)

trainset 


trainsetresult <- <- data.frame("brand" = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, NA), "item" = c(50, 100, 300,200,100,100,100,50,200,300,100,50,200,900)

trainsetresult
```

[trainset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQHaw.jpg)

[trainsetresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6Sgy.jpg)

Further information: the item numbers and also the brand numbers exceed a couple hundreds in the dataframe I am working on.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be with a join, let's try `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(trainset)

trainset[!is.na(brand),][trainset, on = "item", .(brand, item)]
```

Output:

```
    brand item
 1:     1   50
 2:     2  100
 3:     2  100
 4:     3  300
 5:     2  200
 6:     2  100
 7:     2  100
 8:     2  100
 9:     2  100
10:     2  100
11:     2  100
12:     1   50
13:     2  200
14:     3  300
15:     2  100
16:     2  100
17:     1   50
18:     2  200
19:    NA  900
```

You could also use either `minimum` or `maximum` as a replacement, for example with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

trainset %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  mutate(
    brand = ifelse(all(is.na(brand)), NA, min(brand, na.rm = T))
  )
```

Another way is `dplyr` combined with `zoo`, but I think that's an overkill here:

```
trainset %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  arrange(brand) %>%
  mutate(
    brand = zoo::na.locf(brand, na.rm = FALSE)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. After creating a dataframe with just complete and unique rows, it uses `match` to get the positions of the `item` column in that temporary dataframe.

```
tmp <- trainset[complete.cases(trainset), ]
tmp <- tmp[!duplicated(tmp), ]

i <- match(trainset$item, tmp$item)
trainset$brand <- tmp$brand[i]
```

Check if it worked.

```
all.equal(trainset, trainsetresult)
#[1] TRUE
```

Final cleanup.

```
rm(tmp, i)
```